# foreach loop for multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array. how can I get the value of 'installed' key i.e 1. which value I have to check in my application.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53686899
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [installed] => 1
            [id] => 542813519
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        [installed] => 1
            [id] => 567790764
        )
     [3] => Array
        (

            [id] => 567570764
        )
)
```

using foreach loop how can i do this job? anybody can plz help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach ($array as $value){
   if(array_key_exists('installed',$value)){
      echo $value['installed']. "<br />";
   }
}
```

If you are not checking for `array_key_exists` it will show error in first loop.

Comment: If you are not checking for `array_key_exists` it will show error in first loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Prasanth.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
   echo $value['installed']. "<br />";
}
```

will output

1
1

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the same way like when you iterate 1 dimensional array:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($value['installed'];
}
```

Comment: @Debendra Samal: do you have something more objective than your thoughts? And how is it different from the checked answer?

Comment: actually I want to checked in this array whether the array contain installed key or not? If installed key is there, I ll do some operation and if not then also I have some operation.

Comment: @Debendra Samal: "actually I want to checked in this array whether the array contain installed key or not?" --- we cannot read your mind. If you wanted that - you had to impress that by words in the original question

Comment: Btw I got my ans.Thanks to all for kind support.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and get the 'installed' key's value:

```
foreach ($array as $innerArray) {
    echo $innerArray['installed'];
}
```